# I am trying to figure out the crc used in serial communication

Tags: crc16

I am trying to figure out the crc/ checksum used in the following data set. Any one any idea

> 1) 01 03 13 92 00 04 e1 59 0d
>
> 2) 01 03 13 93 00 04 61 4e 0d
>
> 3) 01 03 1b 68 00 04 5d 12 0d
>
> 4) 01 03 1b 5f 00 02 df ad 0d
>
> 5) 01 03 13 96 00 04 61 0a 0d
>
> 6) 01 03 1f 4b 00 02 46 be 0d

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should have provided dataset -> corresponding crc at least.
I can suggest to bruteforce all crc-16 polinomials and see if any of them match all your datacases. It's just 65k variants.

Comment: In this data set 1) 01 03 13 92 00 04 e1 59 0d 

I think e1 59 is the CRC